# How does malware use the Tor network

Tags: tor

How does malware use the Tor network to keep hidden services safe from takedowns

Comment: Same way any other software uses Tor network - by embedding/bundling Tor client, or parts of it, and running it.

Answer (score 2):

Tor can provide anonymity both to clients as well as to servers. A server using Tor for anonymity is called a *hidden service*. The protocol allows a client to connect to a server knowing only an identifier and never needing to know the IP. A high-level overview of this is that the server and client mutually agree on a relay designated the *Rendezvous Point*, which is chosen at random. The server and client then build a three-hop path and rendezvous at this aptly-named relay. They are then free to exchange data with neither side needing to know the other's IP. This can be done for any purpose, including anonymizing a C2.

See the [Tor documentation](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/onion-services) for more information on exactly how this is achieved.

Comment: I am not asking how hidden services work i am aware of hidden services and a very basic understanding of them my question was how does malware use TOR to keep there hidden services safe because my understanding is that the TOR client is required to be able to access the hidden service which would require installing new software

Comment: @Jerry Malware can be packaged either with the Tor binary, or an implementation of the Tor protocol.

Comment: Or am i missing something? I read a article about the client being packaged with the program how is this done? Any future reading would be appreciated and thanks for your answer

Comment: @Jerry Are you asking exactly what code is used to download or install the Tor client? That depends on the specific malware. Malware can download and execute Tor just like any other program.

Comment: Sorry i just now saw your comment how would a attacker pack the Tor binary with the malware and how would they implement the TOR protocol i also read about using a clearnet service such as Tor2Web would this raise a weakness within the design a example is the service logging the hidden service and reporting it to the hosting provider as abuse or something

Comment: No i am asking how the malware uses the client i am aware of how to install TOR

Comment: @Jerry Malware doesn't need to use the official client if it implements the protocol itself or strips the necessary code from Tor, but if it does, then it uses the SOCKS protocol to communicate locally with a running Tor process. It can edit the Tor configuration file ("torrc") to adjust Tor's behavior.

Comment: So the malware starts the TOR client which is invoked by typing tor at the command line and can be used to route requests through TOR using the proxy settings within the application provided you use localhost as the address and the SOCKS proxy port for TOR as the port?

Comment: A few more questions how would it implement the tor protocol? I am aware that the source code is public but i have no idea about implementing protocols or even creating one if you have resources that cover this area and any other reading material for TOR hidden services and malware that abuse them let me know if you do not mind

Comment: @Jerry It wouldn't have to type anything on the command line, of course. As for implementing the protocol, well, they'd just have to do that themselves. They'd read the Tor technical specs and try to implement the subset of the protocol that they wish to use. But really, it's no different from any other use of Tor from the technical perspective. There's nothing that makes malware's use of it particularly unique.

Comment: Alright thanks for the answer i understand now and i was just listing out what i do when configuring a application to use TOR sorry new to the malware ordeal and all

Comment: @Jerry Just a nitpick, but it's Tor, not TOR. Anyway, you should read the Tor documentation to learn exactly how to control the program. Are you trying to write your own malware or something?

Comment: Yes i know but i prefer to call it TOR and yes i am going to head to the TOR website now and read the docs

Comment: I think i figured my own question out thanks to your help this is my idea take Curl and configure it to use a Socks5 proxy using the parameters --socks5 so the whole command would be curl --socks5 socks5://127.0.0.1:9050 https://hiddenservice.onion > Output.txt

Comment: I figured out Curl has the option to use a socks5 proxy instead of the other options like HTTP or FTP from https://superuser.com/questions/1294045/how-to-configure-curl-to-use-always-use-a-socks-proxy Output.txt would be the instructions list and hiddenservice.onion is the hidden service address